# Do open websockets use bandwidth or other resources?

Tags: networking, websocket, server-side

If I have a websocket connection open between a server and a desktop client, is it true that there is no data or bandwidth being used or exchanged between the two except for when I explicitly send some?  And if that is true, does that mean I could essentially have thousands of open connections on a server at a time so long as data was only being transferred very infrequently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically yes. Although the WebSocket protocol has ping/pong frames, and the any of the two ends can send pings periodically and expect pongs as answers, otherwise the would kill the connection.

It would be a very bad idea not implement a "keep alive" mechanism, you won't be able of tell which connections are actually connected or improperly closed.

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Comment: Some of us believe keepalives are a big wart on TCP, making it unnecessarily fragile on low-bandwidth, low-reliability links (_e.g._, amateur satellite communications).

Comment: Don't forget non-bandwidth resources.  On most systems, an open TCP connection (_e.g._, a WebSocket) consumes a variety of limited resources, even with no packet traffic.  Buffer memory and connection control blocks are the most common, but in some systems, port numbers also.

Comment: Ping/pong frames can be as small as two bytes, and to have thousands of connections with little activity is not problem for any modern computer. I do performance testing with thousands of them on my laptop as server. Because mobile devices can lose connection without properly closing the connection, is recommendable to have the keep alive mechanism.

Comment: What about on a cloud server that charges for outgoing bandwidth?